# How to detect a double click on a specific cell in TreeViewer

Tags: java, events, treeview, jface, rcp

In Java, I have a TreeViewer and I am trying to detect a click on a specific cell (not any cell). For example, if I click on a the first cell in a row, I want to detect that the click was made on the first cell in particular.

The following code will fire an event as soon as I double click on a row and it will return all the information about that row. How can I ensure that it will only fire the double click event when I only double click on a particular cell (i.e. a particular row and column).

```
    viewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);        

    viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection thisSelection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();                            
            Object selectedNode = thisSelection.getFirstElement();

            System.out.println(selectedNode.toString());
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

greg-449 is right. The getFirstElement method doesn't have row or col attributes. Here is the answer to greg-449's question why I don't use the cell editing support. In fact, I am using the cell edition support already for one of the columns. Please have a look at the following tree structure:

```
October
  |__(Report 1)(Forecast revenue)(Actual revenue <-- editable)
  |__(Report 2)(Forecast revenue)(Actual revenue <-- editable)
November
  |__(Report 1)(Forecast revenue)(Actual revenue <-- editable)
  |__(Report 2)(Forecast revenue)(Actual revenue <-- editable)
December
  |__(Report 1)(Forecast revenue)(Actual revenue <-- editable)
  |__(Report 2)(Forecast revenue)(Actual revenue <-- editable)
  |__(Report 3)(Forecast revenue)(Actual revenue <-- editable)
```

In the above TreeView, I have 3 main columns: Report, Forecast revenue and Actual revenue. The actual revenue is an editable column which allows the user to enter a value, and that is the column I use the cell editing support. Now when the user double click on the cell of "Report 3" in December, I want to open the corresponding pdf file related to the report 3 in December on a tab. Basically, I want to treat the column 1 (Report) as a double click button to do something corresponding to that particular cell. When the user clicks or double clicks on column 2 "Forecast revenue", it shouldn't do anything. When the user clicks on column 3 Actual revenue", he can enter the actual value. Using the viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {...} as mentioned in my 1st thread, when the user double clicks on column 2 or column 3, it opens the pdf file, which is not what I want! In addition, I have tried to use the cell editing support for column one "Report". If I set the canEdit to true, the column one becomes editable. If I set the canEdit to false, nothing happens. I don't want to edit column 1. I just want to detect the double click event! I hope I've made myself clear this time. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you want to detect clicks on a cell? For some things you can use the cell editing support which will deal with this automatically.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I have elaborated in my question. Can you please have a look? Thanks.

Comment: This does not look at all straightforward. The double click handler has no information abouthe cell. You would have to look at the viewer source to try and work something out,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect a double-click on a particular cell in a TreeView, here is a possible solution which is based on the idea of showing cell tips in a TreeView found on the Internet. 
The mistake I've made was using viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {..}.

```
    Listener treeListener = new Listener () {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            switch (event.type) {                    
                   case SWT.MouseDoubleClick: {
                       Point coords = new Point(event.x, event.y);
                    TreeItem item = viewer.getTree().getItem(coords);

                    if (item != null) {                            
                        int columns = viewer.getTree().getColumnCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                            if (item.getBounds(i).contains(coords)) {
                                   System.out.println("Double Clicked on: " + item.getData() + " : " + i);
                               }
                        }
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    };

    viewer.getTree().addListener (SWT.MouseDoubleClick, treeListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this was great help, I had the same issue!

The viewer.getTree() part however didn't work for me, but I managed to get the result with some small adjustments.

Also, I added a little code to show content of the double-clicked Cell.

```
Listener doubleClickListener = new Listener () {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent (Event event) {
        if (event.type == SWT.MouseDoubleClick) {
           Point coords = new Point(event.x, event.y);
           TableItem item = tableViewer.getTable().getItem(coords);

           if (item != null) {                            
               int columns = tableViewer.getTable().getColumnCount();
               for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                   if (item.getBounds(i).contains(coords)) {
                       if (item.getData() != null) {
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            ArrayList<String> row = (ArrayList<String>)item.getData();
                            if (row.get(i) != null) 
                                System.out.println("Cell contain: " + row.get(i));
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
};
tableViewer.getTable().addListener (SWT.MouseDoubleClick, doubleClickListener);
```

Answer (score -1):

The event will always fire, you should look trough the attributes of selectedNode object, and check if it has any col and row attributes.
Then you just do something like:

```
if(selectedNode.row == theRowYouWant && selectedNode.col == theColYouWant) {
// do something.
}
```

Comment: The getFirstElement method gives you the model object from the content provider. This doesn't have `row` or `col` attributes.